# Documenting Python coroutines with Sphinx autodoc

Tags: python-asyncio, python-sphinx, autodoc

I'm starting to document my first asyncio-based project with Sphinx.  I noticed some projects have this "*coroutine*" prefix before some methods and I'd like to do the same in my project's documentation, but I can't figure out how.

For example, [aiohttp's HTTP client reference](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.org/en/stable/client_reference.html) shows this:

> *class* `aiohttp.ClientSession`(...):
>
> *coroutine* `request`(...)

That project seems to use a `coroutinemethod` directive to achieve this, but I document all my functions and classes inline using docstrings and this directive only works if you write the docs in a reStructuredText document.

Does anybody know how to achieve this result with autodoc?

**Edit**: I will also accept answers that explain how to make a Sphinx extension to do this if Sphinx doesn't support it.  Bonus points if someone can point my to some kind of way that automatically detects whether the method is a coroutine or not using `inspect.iscoroutinefunction()`.

**Edit**: I'm looking at the ["pyspecific" Sphinx extension](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/430a2b541709/Doc/tools/extensions/pyspecific.py) in the CPython project for inspiration.  However, I need to change autodoc's behavior, not add new directives.  After a bit of research, it looks like autodoc has an [autodoc-process-signature event](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html#event-autodoc-process-signature) which can be used to customize the function signature, but it doesn't seem to have the object used by the "pyspecific" extension.

Answer (score 3):

This functionality is not already built-in to Sphinx.  However, [pull request #1826](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/pull/1826) adds support for generators, coroutine functions, coroutine methods with built-in detection of coroutines in autodoc's `autofunction` and `automethod` directives.

Here is a patch that I applied locally to enable this in Sphinx 1.4 (requires disabling `sphinx-build`'s `-W` "turn warnings into errors" option):

```
# Recipe stolen from open PR (https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/pull/1826).


from inspect import iscoroutinefunction

from sphinx import addnodes
from sphinx.domains.python import (
    PyClassmember,
    PyModulelevel,
)
from sphinx.ext.autodoc import FunctionDocumenter as _FunctionDocumenter
from sphinx.ext.autodoc import MethodDocumenter as _MethodDocumenter


class PyCoroutineMixin(object):
    """Helper for coroutine-related Sphinx custom directives."""

    def handle_signature(self, sig, signode):
        ret = super(PyCoroutineMixin, self).handle_signature(sig, signode)
        signode.insert(0, addnodes.desc_annotation('coroutine ', 'coroutine '))
        return ret


class PyCoroutineFunction(PyCoroutineMixin, PyModulelevel):
    """Sphinx directive for coroutine functions."""

    def run(self):
        self.name = 'py:function'
        return PyModulelevel.run(self)


class PyCoroutineMethod(PyCoroutineMixin, PyClassmember):
    """Sphinx directive for coroutine methods."""

    def run(self):
        self.name = 'py:method'
        return PyClassmember.run(self)


class FunctionDocumenter(_FunctionDocumenter):
    """Automatically detect coroutine functions."""

    def import_object(self):
        ret = _FunctionDocumenter.import_object(self)
        if not ret:
            return ret

        obj = self.parent.__dict__.get(self.object_name)
        if iscoroutinefunction(obj):
            self.directivetype = 'coroutine'
            self.member_order = _FunctionDocumenter.member_order + 2
        return ret


class MethodDocumenter(_MethodDocumenter):
    """Automatically detect coroutine methods."""

    def import_object(self):
        ret = _MethodDocumenter.import_object(self)
        if not ret:
            return ret

        obj = self.parent.__dict__.get(self.object_name)
        if iscoroutinefunction(obj):
            self.directivetype = 'coroutinemethod'
            self.member_order = _MethodDocumenter.member_order + 2
        return ret


def setup(app):
    """Sphinx extension entry point."""

    # Add new directives.
    app.add_directive_to_domain('py', 'coroutine', PyCoroutineFunction)
    app.add_directive_to_domain('py', 'coroutinemethod', PyCoroutineMethod)

    # Customize annotations for anything that looks like a coroutine.
    app.add_autodocumenter(FunctionDocumenter)
    app.add_autodocumenter(MethodDocumenter)

    # Return extension meta data.
    return {
        'version': '1.0',
        'parallel_read_safe': True,
    }
```